# Filename encoding with base64 in MSIE

Tags: java, file, encoding, base64

I have a method:

```
  private String encodeFileAttachment(HttpServletRequest request, String filename) throws IOException {
String userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
if (userAgent.contains("Mozilla") && !userAgent.contains("MSIE")) {
    return "=?UTF-8?B?" + new String(Base64.encodeBase64(filename.getBytes("UTF-8")), "UTF-8") + "?=";
} else {
    return filename = URLEncoder.encode(filename, "UTF-8");
 }
}
```

and filename like:

sss zzz ddd.png

firefox return something like this:
[image: image1]
but msie return [image: image 2]

So probably encode method change " " to '+'
That problem occurs only in Internet Explorer. Could somebody tell me why?

Comment: Are you aware that your URLEncoder.encode() is not called for FireFox? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: I realize it. But that encode  well can do the trick with special characters. The problem was with spaces (" "). Could you help me with that problem ?

Comment: I will mention that solution was checking on other browsers and the problem occurs only in MSIE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaves as expected. The URLEncoder implements the HTML Specifications for how to encode URLs in HTML forms.

From the javadocs:

```
This class contains static methods for converting a String to the application/x-www-form-urlencoded MIME format.
```

and from the HTML Specification:

```
    1. Control names and values are escaped. Space characters are replaced by `+'
```

Solution:

```
URLEncoder.encode(filename, "utf-8").replaceAll("\\+", " ");
```